# RESTful way of handling notifications

Tags: rest

Say I want a user to be notified whenever his or her blog post receives a new comment. The notification should be received upon a browser refresh (i.e. no web sockets needed).

I am considering between two implementations for my REST api:

**1) Client submits POST requests to /comments followed by /notifications**

- Once the server indicates that a POST request to /comments is successful, the client will proceed to submit another POST request to /notifications.

**2) Client submits POST request to /comments and server creates notification**

- When a POST request is made to /comments, the server manually creates a new notification resource and adds it to the database.

Method 1 seems neater as I do not have to sprinkle the creation of notification logic across other endpoints that require notifications. It also doesn't require side-effects. However, method 1 would allow users to post custom notification messages to `/notifications`. In addition, it would be vulnerable to the edge case where after the first POST request is made successfully to `/comments`, but the second POST request to `/notifications` somehow fails (maybe due to network issue). Method 2 can circumvent this problem by using transactions, where a notification resource isn't created if the initial creation of comment fails.

I would like to get some feedback on how is a notification system typically implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option 2 is probably the typical approach. Imagine you have multiple clients using your API, now you need to trust all those clients to create the notification for each thing they do. If they forget, no notification.

Side-effects like this are typically encapsulated by the server.

The first option is not strictly *wrong*, just very unusual.